# Firestore Snapshot listeners 30 minute disconnect on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I read the following on a [guide](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-drastically-reduce-the-number-of-reads-when-no-documents-are-changed-in-firestore-8760e2f25e9e) someone wrote about Firestore:

"Basically, we pay 50 reads once we attach the listener and one read for each addition or update of a document. However, if the listener is disconnected for more than 30 minutes, we’ll be charged for reads as if we had issued a brand-new query. In the worst-case scenario, if the listener is disconnected every 31 minutes, we pay 50 reads each time."

Question: Does this mean that upon opening the application again after 30 minutes, the Firebase SDK reconnects all of the snapshot listeners again?

I’m really just trying to understand what exactly happens in the background once that 30 minutes has passed and the user opens the application again.

Comment: "a guide someone wrote about Firestore" Please provide a link, so we can check for more context and authoritativeness.

Comment: https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-drastically-reduce-the-number-of-reads-when-no-documents-are-changed-in-firestore-8760e2f25e9e

Comment: Let's see if @AlexMamo is available to comment himself. :)

Comment: We’ve essentially had a problem with our customers locking their device and coming back to it hours later and the performance is bad for ~20 seconds. The customer tries to click the UI and the app doesn’t respond during the 20 second duration. I was trying to figure out what Firestore does to reconnect/resync the data. We use snapshot listeners and the users could have anywhere from 10 to a few thousand listeners at any given time. I thought the resyncing could be the culprit of the performance hit once the user unlocks their device.

Comment: @YaDunSayThat a single client can have a few thousand listeners running at any given time?

Comment: @liquid Yea - we add a snapshot on customers/{customerNumber}/orders/{orderUUID}/items
And within that collection - any item (items/{itemID}) added has a listener tied to it for if it gets add/edited/deleted
Some of our customers add more than a thousand distinct items to their order.

Comment: @YaDunSayThat I know nothing about your project but a few thousand listeners per client at any given time raises some serious concerns to me about either how the data is architected or the expectations of the UX. Are you aware that Firestore best practices are to keep snapshot listeners per client under 100? Maybe Firestore is not the platform for you with these kinds of demands?

Comment: @liquid Maybe what I said wasn't accurate so I will try to explain a little better.

We add a snapshot on the collection: customers/{customerNumber}/orders/{orderUUID}/items with the following code in iOS:

let query = Firestore.firestore().collection(path).document(orderId).collection("items")
        let listener = query.addSnapshotListener

We only call addSnapshotListener once. but for any item that is added to the /items collection the listener is triggered.   
So is there a snapshot listener for every item or is it just technically one snapshot listener for the whole collection?

Comment: @YaDunSayThat that makes more sense. We are dealing with just one snapshot listener, in this case. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @liquid So i'm really just trying to figure out if after that 30 minutes is up... firebase is completely refreshing what could be thousands of items in that /items collection and that's what is causing the performance hit or if it could be something else.

Comment: @YaDunSayThat after 30 minutes of disconnection, the listener will definitely go to the server for documents. That's not to say, though, that it won't go to the server sooner if the query set has changed. If the listener was reconnected within 30 minutes and the cache can satisfy the query, then you will get cached documents, otherwise live documents. I suggest you test this to see if the performance hit is from this mechanism. Observe a very large query that you know will not change and monitor performance when reconnecting before 30 minutes and then after 30 minutes and compare the results.

Comment: @YaDunSayThat btw, as part of your testing, the listener can return metadata which will tell you if the documents are from cache or the server. The metadata properties you might find of interest are `isFromCache` and `hasPendingWrites`.

Comment: @YaDunSayThat one last thing to consider is pagination to soften the performance hit whatever is causing it. You can paginate results from snapshot listeners. The process, however, requires some extra steps beyond those for static get-document requests but it is definitely doable.